# What sort of 'client requests per second' can IdentityServer4 handle in Azure?

Tags: azure, identityserver4

Our [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) will be hosted in Azure. I know it will depend on the performance plan, so lets assume a database of 300 DTUs.

Is there a limit at all?

Is there a recommended performance plan for an expected load?

Does it largely depend on the capability defined by the Azure service plan, such as 'Max concurrent sessions'?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at this DTU calculator - http://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net

Or, read through the section on plans here -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers

For 300 DTUs, looking at the DOCs above, the standard plan (which can go up to 3000 DTUs) would be a good choice. If you are looking to save some money, I would recommend using the Elastic Pool option, under the standard plan. If performance is key, and money is not a concern, then down use Elastic Pool

Comment: Thanks, but this is specifically an IdentityServer4 question